# Как вывести заголовки на сайте?

Tags: python, django

В djnago есть order_by,там указывают поле которое хотят вывести,вот я и хочу вывести все заголовки на сайт,но при выводится <QuerySet [<News: Epic Games через суд добивается восстановления учётной записи в App Store>, <News: Киберпанк выйдет в 2020!>]>, как сделать так что бы выводились просто слова,а не список?

Comment: Ничего не понял,что такое object,не понял ничего!

Comment: Я хочу вывести все загаловки на сайт что бы они не были как представлено тут:<QuerySet [<News: Epic Games через суд добивается восстановления учётной записи в App Store>, <News: Киберпанк выйдет в 2020!>]>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for n in news %}
    <h1>{{ n }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Просто создать цикл в котором news - переменная, переданная в контекст. news будет хранить статьи( `news=Model.objects.all()` ). Да и вы не совсем поняли, что такое order_by. Он сортирует записи по определенному полю, по определенному порядку и количеству.

Comment: Спасибо, я всё понял!

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите сделать.

`order_by('')` указывает Django в каком порядке отсортировать queryset. Например, у вас в модели Articles есть поле `updated`. Если вы хотите получить экземпляры статей, отсортированных в порядке обновления, то запрос queryset будет выглядеть так `Articles.objects.all().order_by('updated')`. Прочитайте подробнее о `order_by` в [официальной документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) ([перевод на русском](https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by))

Если вы хотите вывести на сайте заголовки новостей, в шаблоне используйте следующий код:

```
{% for objects in news %}
    <h1>{{ object.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Для этого вы должны передать в шаблон queryset. Как один из вариантов, используйте в представлении

```py
...
context = {
    'news': News.objects.all()
}
return render(request, 'news.html', context)
```

Узнайте больше про использование queryset [здесь](https://django.fun/docs/django/ru/3.1/ref/models/querysets/)