# Вывести все заголовки на сайте

Tags: python, django

Вот с помощью чего я могу вывести все заголовки на сайте? Допустим я беру `order_by('заголовки')` и он мне выводит их в списке

```
<QuerySet [<News: Epic Games через суд добивается восстановления учётной записи в App Store>, <News: Киберпанк выйдет в 2020!>]>
```

как сделать так что бы они не выводились в списке?

Comment: Заголовки на сайте можно вывести с помощью xPath и, к примеру, beautifulsoup4.

Comment: А как с помощью django?

Comment: покажи, что у тебя есть в проекте, что бы понять чего тебе не хватает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести заголовки на сайте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186927/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой вопрос уже был. Используйте решение отсюда [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186927/Как-вывести-заголовки-на-сайте/1186936#1186936](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186927/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5/1186936#1186936)

Хотите вывести заголовке в коде?

```py
def print_headers():
    for obj in YourModel.objects.all().order_by('field_name'):
    print(obj.header_field_name)
```

`order_by()` — это способ отсортировать полученный Queryset по определенному полю.